# compile error called subscript out of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple columns please how would i provide a range please 
           help me out i am adding colums to mysql database

```
  aWidth = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:FA1")) 'Finds the width of the table - if you have more columns than that, just extend the range
  aHeight = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A65536")) - 1 'Finds the height of the  table, minus the field names - if you have more rows than that, just extend the range
  count = 0 'Will be used throughout the macro as a counter
  count_2 = 0 'Will be used throughout the macro as a counter
  count_3 = 0 'Will be used throughout the macro as a counter

  '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  'Populate the table row
  '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ReDim array_fields(aWidth)

  'This will populate INTO what the VALUES will go for the whole upload
  Do Until count = aWidth
  count = count + 1 'Set the count to be used in the array and increment it for the the   
  Do
  cell = Worksheets("Upload").Cells(1, count).Value
  array_fields(count) = cell
  Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what you are attempting but I think the macro below will help set you in the right direction.

Create a new workbook, open VBA editor, create a module and copy the macro below into the module.

Copy `="R"&ROW(A1)&"-C"&COLUMN(A1)` to cell A1 of worksheet Sheet1.  This formula is not essential but will show the effect I wish to demonstrate very clearly.

Copy cell A1 across and then copy row 1 down to create a small rectangle (say 5*10) of values.

Run the macro.

The statement `cellValue = .UsedRange.Value` imports the entire used range of worksheet "Sheet1" as an array and stores it in Variant `cellValue`.

With two-dimensional arrays, the convention is to have columns as the first dimension and rows as the second dimension.  Arrays filled by loading a range are the other way round.

The statement `cellValue = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.UsedRange.Value)` also imports the range but swaps row and columns.

If you have to copy a row of values to a one-dimensional array before writing the 1-D array to your database, the transpose will be of little value.  However, if you can write a two-dimensional array, it may get the data into just the format you require for a single write.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()

  Dim cellValue As Variant
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    cellValue = .UsedRange.Value

    For RowCrnt = 1 To UBound(cellValue, 2)
      For ColCrnt = 1 To UBound(cellValue, 1)
        Debug.Print "|" & cellValue(ColCrnt, RowCrnt);
      Next
      Debug.Print "|"
    Next

    Debug.Print ("-----------------------------------------")

    cellValue = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.UsedRange.Value)

    For RowCrnt = 1 To UBound(cellValue, 2)
      For ColCrnt = 1 To UBound(cellValue, 1)
        Debug.Print "|" & cellValue(ColCrnt, RowCrnt);
      Next
      Debug.Print "|"
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```